# Angular child component reconstructed on async pipe resubscription

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am using 'ngFor' directive to initialize a list of child components:

Parent component:

```
 <div *ngFor="let item of serviceGetter.items | async; let i = index">
     <child-component [item]="item" [currentIndex]="i"></child-component>
</div>
```

Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class TermsService {

   private dataStore: {
     data: any[];
   } = { data: [] };

   get items() {
     return this._data$.asObservable();
   }

   //data are populated inside this method
   someMethod() {
      this.dataStore.data= result;
      this._data$.next(Object.assign({}, this.dataStore).data);
   }

   updateSpecificItem() {
       ....          

      this.dataStore.data[index] = {
         ...somedata,
      };
   }
}
```

'Child component' change detection is set to 'OnPush'.
The problem is when 'updateSpecificItem()' function is called child component at 'index' position is reinitialized(constructor call). Is there a solution to avoid this or is this the accepted behavior?

Comment: The instance changes, so the for loop is rerun. This is expected. You could try to use a trackBy in your for loop to prevent unwanted rerenders.

Comment: https://blog.bitsrc.io/angular-optimization-use-trackby-option-for-ngfor-directive-72c9509b2be9

Comment: trackBy was the solution...thanks all